# c# listbox multiselect, selectedItems winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I saw many examples of getting the values from selectedItems, but in my case I would like to somehow separate these values. What I mean is, for example if I have in my list options like `work` `home` `forrest` `car`, I would like to be able after choosing `work` and `home` to get both text separated and save them in some string variable. 
Now I am doing it this way:

```
string text = "";
foreach (var item in customListBox1.SelectedItems)
{
     text += item.ToString() + " ";
}
```

Later I am filtering datagridview based on this selecteditems in such way:

```
var result = list3.Where(Srodek => Srodek.Srodek.category1 == text);
```

That is why I need them separated. How can I do it?
If something is not clear, please let me know, I will try to explain it more.

Comment: What's the problem with the current way you use?

Comment: That this string text is holding information like this: `work home` and inside my object `Srodek` field `category1` holds strings separated, like `work`, `home`. So it cannot match them like this while filtering. Hope I made it clear.

Comment: you want a `comma separated strings`? see my answer if it helps.

Comment: I want to get both vlues in separated strings. Like text1 will hold `work` value and text2 holds `home` and so on. Depands on how many things you choose from listbox. Can I do it?

Comment: but your example shows that you want a single `string` not a list or array of strings?

Comment: I know, because I tried to do this way and failed. I just wanted to show that I have put some effort in solving my problem. Thank you for help. Damith answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var list  = customListBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<string>().ToList();
var result = list3.Where(Srodek => list.Any(x=>x == Srodek.Srodek.category1));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something better like this:

```
string text = string.Join(",", customListBox1.SelectedItems.OfType<Object>().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```